# How to handle IndirectLookUp datatype in Odata Service Metadata(odata.raml) for Mule 4

Tags: salesforce, mule, odata, mulesoft, mule4

In Salesforce External Datasource we are trying to Consuming Mule Application via Odata.
As part of this, client requirement is for one of the field datatype is IndirectLookup which links to Opportunity Table field. In Mule 4, while creating odata raml, i need to know how to handle IndirectLookup datatype. I tried with datatype as text it failed as below
***field type doesn't match. In Salesforce : "IndirectLookup". In data source : "Text"***

[image]

Mule Runtime:
<app.runtime>4.4.0-20220221</app.runtime>

Odata Dependency:

org.mule.modules mule-module-apikit-odata 2.2.0 mule-plugin

Please find the screenshot of the error steps

1. Freight field is Indirectlookup datatype

[image]

[image]
2. In Mule Sidee, metadata endpoint response below where Freight field is String. **Error Freight_c field doesn't match. In Salesforce : "IndirectLookup". In data source : "Text"**
[image]

[image]

Comment: Where are you seeing that message? What version of Mule and the OData module are you using?

Comment: @aled  I am seeing this error in Salesforce --> External Data Source, when try to sync custom object seeing tht error. Mule version 4.4.0E, Odata dependency we use as below           
               <dependency>
   <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
   <artifactId>mule-module-apikit-odata</artifactId>
   <version>2.2.0</version>
   <classifier>mule-plugin</classifier>
  </dependency>

Comment: Please don't add the details in comments. Use the edit button and add them to your question. Mule 4.4.0E doesn't seem to be a valid version. Please use the exact version.

Comment: I just updated correct app number in the question. Seems that is the latest version we are using.

Comment: That's not correct. At this time there is a 2.2.1 release. Also there is an APIKit ODATA V4 mdoule with a different version number though I'm not sure of the differences: https://docs.mulesoft.com/release-notes/apikit/apikit-release-notes. Also add the complete error from the log with all details to the question. Please read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). See why to post [complete errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359146/why-should-i-post-complete-errors-why-isnt-the-message-itself-enough)

Comment: Add the error details, not sure what is the issue i am banging my head :(